# How to return data coming from response

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that starts by executing the getName function, and then when some data gets into the else block of the getPlace function, instead of a regular object, I get a subscriber (as you can see in the screenshot), although in theory I subscribe to changes where I assign values. it can be fixed?
[image]

[image]

Comment: welcome, please put your code in text mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you can't treat an http request (the http.get) as procedural code. The http request is asynchronous and the code within the `.pipe()` method is only executed *after* the data is returned from the server.

So your `getPlace()` method, won't be able to simply return `data` by calling the `_getPlace()` method.

Instead of fighting against the way this works and trying to "fix" it. I would suggest that you handle *both* as Observables.

My code in a similar situation looks like this:

**Service**

```
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    if (this.products) {
        return of(this.products);
    }
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productsUrl)
        .pipe(
            tap(data => console.log('All Products', JSON.stringify(data))),
            tap(data => this.products = data),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}
```

**Component**

```
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe({
        next: (products: IProduct[]) => {
            this.products = products;
        },
        error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
```

Here, if the data has already been cached, it uses the RxJS `of` operator to convert the data back into an Observable.

That way you can subscribe to the result of getProducts and you'll get the cached data OR the retrieved data.

NOTE: Another option is to use RxJS declaratively and leverage the RxJS `shareReplay(1)` operator to automatically provide the caching for you. For more information on this technique, check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck&t=517s

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe the function for getting the value

```
 public nameList :any;
    this.getPlace(placeId).subscribe(data => {
    //data hold your expected response
    this.nameList =data;
    
    });
```

Comment: Then I get the error This.getPlace (...). Subscribe is not a function. Actually, I have the same logic in the getplace function, but if I don't explicitly assign let data = this._getPlace (placeId) .subscribe ... but write let data; and then under it a subscription to getplace, then 3 undefined will arrive in data @Jobelle

Answer (score 0):

Observable are asynchronous and javascript use a single thread environment.
If the javascript thread detects any async task, the task are handed to enclosing environment(Browser etc.) to execute it in a seperate thread.
So your code runs like this.

1. Main Thread call this._getPlace()
2. Checks the statement this._getPlace() and hands off the execution to other thread.
3. Main Thread return data variable (which is null) - this happens before Step2 is finished.

That's why the data returned is null.

To solve your problem, use`map` instead of `subscribe`

```
 if(this._place.has(placeId)){
    return this._places.get(placeId)
  } else { 
    let data: any = this.getPlace(placeId).map( place => {
                                                    //do something here
                                                    //return something
                                                    }).first()
    return data;
  }
```

Comment: Than i got an error Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Partial<IPlace>> @acer23